# Calculating radii allowing for circular placement of polygonal linkage's joints

Tags: algorithms, plane-geometry, linkage

Given a planar polygonal linkage defined by a sequence of $n$ hinge joints $(j_0,\,\cdots,\,j_{n-1},j_n = j_0)$ with links of fixed lengths $\lbrace\|j_{k+1}-j_k\|=d_k\ |\ 0\le k\lt n\rbrace$ between adjacent joints,

> how can the set of radii be calculated that allow for placing all joints of the linkage on a circle with such a radius, while preserving the lengths of its links?

In view of the answers I want to stress that all joint shall lie on the *same* circle and, that the linkage is cyclically closed, i.e. its joints and links resemble a connected 2-regular graph.
There is already a question that is related to polygonal linkages: [Is the area of a polygonal linkage maximized by having all vertices on a circle?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22767/is-the-area-of-a-polygonal-linkage-maximized-by-having-all-vertices-on-a-circle) which however was not concerned with determining the radius of the circle on which all joints lie when the area enclosed by the linkage is maximal.

Being able to calculate the smallest and the largest of those radii would be sufficient for my purposes, which I will state in a later edit.

In reply to the answers I'd like to add the following findings:

- a sharp lower bound for the radius on which all joints of a linkage can simultaneously lie, can be found by differentiating the radius of the circumcircle of a triangle w.r.t. one of its side-lengths:
  $$\frac{\partial\left(\frac{x\,y\,z}{\sqrt{2(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)-(x^4+y^4+z^4)}}\right)}{\partial x}=0\iff x=\sqrt{z^2-y^2} $$
  which indicates that the circumcircle of a pair of adjacent links is minimal if the longer of the two is the hypotenuse of a right triangle and that the lower bound for entire linkage equals the maximum of all those minima.
- if one divides the link-lengths by the by the sought radius, the resulting values are of the form $2\sin\left(\frac{\varphi_{ij}}{2}\right)$ and function for determining the radius can set up via the trigonometric addition theorems; that function can in turn be converted to rational one by utilizig $$\sin\left(\frac{\varphi_{ij}}{2}\right)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\quad \text{and}\quad \cos\left(\frac{\varphi_{ij}}{2}\right)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has an algebraic-number solution (set up a system of quadratic equalities between the squared link lengths and the squared distances between hinge points) but with unsolvable Galois groups, so there is not going to be a nice closed formula solution. See: Varfolomeev, V.V.: Galois groups of the Heron–Sabitov polynomials for inscribed pentagons. Mat. Sb. 195 (2004) 3–16 Translation in Sb. Math. 195: 149–162, 2004.

Answer (score 1):

Let the radius be $r$.  Of course we need $r \ge d_k/2$ for all $k$.  If $\theta_k$ is the angular coordinate of joint $j_k$, with say $\theta_0 = 0$, we have 
$$ \theta_{k+1} - \theta_k = \pm 2 \arcsin(d_k/(2r))$$
and we need $\theta_{n} = 2 \pi m$ for some integer $m$. By symmetry we may assume the first $\pm$ is $+$, so there are potentially $2^{n-1}$ choices there.

I suspect that for moderately large $n$ it may be best to handle this numerically, though in principle we could use a system of polynomials.

Comment: It should be noted that the set of radii can be empty, suggesting the challenge of maximizing the number of hinge points lying on a circular arc. (Are the joints supposed to lie in cyclic order, or does one double back as Robert seems to assume?) Gerhard "Starting The Arc Of 2020" Paseman, 2020.01.01.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman the joints shall all lie on a *single* circle and the question amounts to for which radii that is possible; I see that I have to edit my question to make that point more explicit.

Comment: @Manfred, indeed I am mistaken about the set of radii being empty; my bicycle chain argument suggests otherwise. However, I am using the fact that the linkage is like a bicycle chain.  Gerhard "In A Mechanically Topological Sense" Paseman, 2020.01.02.

Answer (score 1):

Some  simple reductions.

For n=2 and 3 (rigid linkages) , there is a unique answer. Scaling the problem so that the longest link has length one, this results in radii between $1/2$ and $1/s$ where $s^2=3$. Depending on parity, these are also the absolute minimum values of radii possible.

If one is wiling to settle for a near optimum, one can do a "bicycle chain" argument (assuming a really accommodating chain and appropriate pipe, but hey, such assumptions are part of the benefits package of a theoretician), place the chain in a pipe of appropriate parity (or hopeful diameter) and start placing the chain in the pipe so that many links are flexed to touch the inner diameter of the pipe. One may get many joints on the inner surface, and one may be able to manage all but one joint this way on the pipe.  The reason for this argument is that one can attempt to predict the discrepancy, and then adjust the pipe toward a more accommodating diameter.  In particular, if one can do this while keeping one joint outside of the pipe after each intermediate placement, one can by continuity estimate an exact radius, which for large n should not differ much from the trial radius.

For lengths all the same, one can do stellar patterns by tracing a pattern on a regular ngon (for k relatively prime to n, place link j on point jk mod n).  The desired radii should be easily calculated and are probably in the literature (for some interesting value of 'literature').  This gives for this special case a starting set of radii, and one wonders if between two such radii there is an intermediate radius that has a (most likely nonregular) link placement.

A correction to Robert's post: The set of radii can be infinite for some cases with even n: just use an arc. I suspect the set of radii is finite for odd n.

Gerhard "Building A Circle Of Ideas" Paseman, 2020.01.01.

Comment: Here is a nice way to see the infinite set of radii for even n=2m: take an open ended linkage of m links, and place it on a large arc. Now reflect a copy across the (perpendicular bisector of the) arc, making a closed linkage of n links on that arc.  Gerhard "Building Linked Circle Of Ideas" Paseman, 2020.01.01.

Comment: Gerhard, thanks for your answer but it appears to me that you have overlooked the condition that the linkage is a cyclic one and thus the smallest non-trivial case consists of $n=4$ links. It is the cyclicity what makes the problem hard to solve explicitly.

Comment: @Manfred, I don't think so. If (when drawn on the plane) the links do not intersect, then one has a different problem. For n=4, assume the links are the sides of a rectangle. I maintain that the set of radii is infinite.  If my picture is wrong for this case, please edit to include what cases you are considering for n=4. Gerhard "Trying To Frame Correct Question" Paseman, 2020.01.02.

Comment: Ok, I now see what I had in mind, but didn't mention; you are of course right, if no restriction is made on the turning angles; my silent condition is however that all turns are to the same side, e.g. to the left when traversing the polygon. Sorry for that omission.